# Arduino IDE to program Arduino Galileo

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Did anyone get the new `Arduino` `Galileo` `microprocessor` board yet? I was wondering if anyone had a any luck using the current version of `Arduino IDE` to program `Galileo`.

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation under Programming it says that it works with the current arduino IDE.
http://arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo

Answer (score 0):

Intel board will give you two com ports. One of them is virtual com. 
You can use virtual com to load the program with Arduino ide. Another one is used for accessing os in processor with putty or any other serial communication program.